# javascript d3.js date string parsing issue

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, d3.js

assume this is my string in my data object

`{ date: "2013-03-04 12:00:00+0000" }`

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S+%Z");

data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        });
```

yet in my `forEach` method, my date object returns null every time. I don't understand why this fails.

Similarly

`{ date: "2013-03-04 00:00:00+0000" }`

with

`d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00+00").parse`

works fine. But the date is less precise because it assumes everything happens at midnight in my visualization

Why is my string date parser failing with my first scenario? I tried stepping through the date parser in console/inspect element in chrome, but to no avail.

here are the d3.time.format documents https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Comment: You might not need the [+] in [+%Z]. Try ["%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S%Z"]

Comment: @Andrew this did not work either `d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S%Z").parse`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation page that you link to, further down:

> The following directives are not yet supported for parsing:
>
> %j - day of the year.
>
> %U - week number of the year.
>
> %w - weekday number.
>
> %W - week number of the year.
>
> %Z - time zone offset, such as "-0700".
>
> %% - a literal "%" character.

The time zone offset you're trying to parse is not supported. The second one works because you're not trying to parse that.

If you're fine with everything being in GMT, just replace the `+%Z` with `+0000` in your format specification. Otherwise, you'll have to find another way of parsing dates.

Comment: this did not work `d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S+0000").parse`

Comment: this worked d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+0000").parse  thanks, took a lot of trial and error. The documents suggest that _ is needed for a space, but that was misleading