# Parse Date by YEAR-WEEK pattern in JavaScript and D3

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

i have a line chart in D3 where i can aggregate the values within the char to days, weeks, month and year.

For that purpose i deliver differnt date formats within my chart data.

DAYS: 2005-12-31

WEEK: 2005-26

MONTH: 2005-12

YEAR: 2005

Within D3 those patterns can be parsed with

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format(settings.d3pattern).parse;
```

Oficially, according to the current version of D3, the week pattern can be parsed with %Y-%U. There is no information about problems with the %U pattern as stated in [javascript d3.js date string parsing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229514/javascript-d3-js-date-string-parsing-issue) . But i'm getting an error when i try to parse the week format.

The only parsing concern is "The %Z directive (time zone offset, such as "-0700") is not yet supported for parsing." Source: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Can someone please comment 1. Other methods to parse dates by a week based pattern. Tools like moment.js do not offer a pattern for the week of the year and 2. Should D3 in the current version be able to parse this date or not.

Answer (score 0):

See the first comment of [How to convert a week number to a date in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580824/how-to-convert-a-week-number-to-a-date-in-javascript) : it gets a pretty complete and tested method to get the first day of a year+week.